# Android: When to call invalidate()?

Tags: android, invalidation, ui-thread

I'm using Matrix to rotate a PNG image on the screen. I want to move the rotation operation to a separate thread so the UI thread isn't burdened with it. But this raises some interesting questions.

I expected to need to call invalidate() once the Matrix was applied to the ImageView. However, the rotated image is appearing just fine on the screen - and I never call invalidate(). There are no touch areas, nothing I'm doing would explicitly tell the UI to refresh the screen. What is stimulating the UI thread to update the display? Does the UI thread magically "know" that the display needs to be updated (and therefore an explicit call to invalidate() is not necessary) because IT is the thread touching an object that is part of the display?

When I move the rotation out of the UI thread, I will be manipulating the same ImageView that the UI uses to render the screen. This sounds like a classic thread conflict problem that would require synchronization (because the same object will be accessed by multiple threads). But because of the above behavior, I'm not sure how this is handled. Since the UI thread seems to "magically know" that the screen needs to be updated, do I NEED to synchronize - or does the separate thread just call invalidate() on the View and that will take care of it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is `postInvalidate()` from a non-UI thread, as opposed to `invalidate()` when on the UI thread.

But yes.

Just call this, and it will update on the next given chance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you did not have to call invalidate is that the `setImageDrawable` (and similar methods) method of ImageView invalidates itself already.

In addition, it's a bad idea to modify Views in a separate thread. Move the View manipulation into `onPostExecute` and leave the Bitmap manipulation in `doInBackground`.

Comment: Yes, I presumed it is a bad idea to manipulate Views from non-UI threads (classic thread conflict). Normally I would synchronize multiple threads for such situations, but the weird self-invalidation behavior made me wonder if there are "special rules" for this UI situation. I am not familiar with onPostExecute and doInBackground, but will research. It seems to me that I would need to have a separate ImageView, alter that in the separate thread, and then swap it in for the other ImageView - hence having two ImageViews that alternate between the threads.